# Absolute continuity of measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu, \nu$ be two measures. Show that $\nu <<\mu $ does not imply $\mu E = 0 \Rightarrow \nu E = 0$ by constructing a suitable example.

Now here absolute continuity of measure $\nu <<\mu$ is defined by saying  $|\mu E| = 0 \Rightarrow \nu E=0$

I tried to see if I can find some set which doesn't follow the condition assuming $\mu$ as L measure adn $\nu E := \int_{E} f$

Comment: If $\mu$ is a positive measure, then $|\mu E|=\mu E$ for all $E$.  So to get a counterexample you need to take a measure that is not always positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $\mu$ is a signed measure.

Take $X= \{0,1\}$, $\mu (\{0\})=1,\mu(\{1\})=-1$. Set $\nu=|\mu|$, that is $\nu(\{0\})=\nu(\{1\})=1$. But  $0=\mu(X)\ne \nu(X)=2$.